# Pandas, Python. Replace random subset of values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a data frame from which a specific column (y1) has 3 possible values: -9, 1 and 2.

I would like to change  a random sample of 1000 values which originally were 2  to -9.

I have tried this:

```
df.loc[df.y1 == "2", 'y1'].sample(1000) =="-9"
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `index` of values for change first and then assign:

There is problem if number of rows of filtered `a` is less as `1000`, so `min` was added - so it return length of `a` if `length < 1000`:

```
a = df.loc[df.y1 == 2, 'y1']
df.loc[a.sample(min(len(a.index), 1000)).index, 'y1'] = -9
```

Thank you, [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542422/pandas-python-replace-random-subset-of-values-in-a-column/45542502?noredirect=1#comment78045174_45542502) for better solution, if possible no `2` in column `y1`:

```
df.loc[(a if len(a.index) < 1000 else a.sample(1000)).index, 'y1'] = -9
```

Comment: Minor quibble, will raise an issue when `a` is an empty dataframe, would you prefer `(a if len(a.index) < 1000 else a.sample(1000)).index` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Because while you use "==" the right way for your index, you merely should use "=" for the second one to assign the -9 value

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I tried:  df.loc[df.y1 == "2", 'y1'].sample(1000) ="-9". but does not work

Comment: aActually there were two mistakes indeed, and I answered too quickly, I should have read the sample function first